# Sequentially counting repeated entries

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am currently working on a project where I have to measure someones activity over time on a site, based on whether they edit a site. I have a data frame that looks similar to this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"x":["a", "b", "c", "b","b"],
               "y":["red", "blue", "green", "yellow","red"],
               "z":[1,2,3,4,5]})
```

I want to add a column to the dataframe such that it counts the number of repeated values (number of edits, which is column x) there are, using the "z" column as the measure of when the events happened.

E.g. to have an additional column of:

```
df["activity"] = pd.Series([1,1,1,2,3])
```

How would I best go about this in Python? Not sure what my best approach here is.

Comment: Are you looking for `df.groupby('x').cumcount() + 1`?

Comment: `df.groupby('x').cumcount().add(1)`

Comment: `using the "z" column as the measure of when the events happened.` What does this mean?

Comment: @Wen Yeah thats exactly what I need, thank you

Comment: @Wen... do you want to write an answer?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ nope :-)

Comment: @Wen Okay, I wrote a community wiki, since the answer belongs to us both. ;-)

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ that is fine , if you turn it to an answer , will upvote :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### `groupby` and `cumcount`

```
df['activity'] = df.groupby('x').cumcount() + 1
df

   x       y  z  activity
0  a     red  1         1
1  b    blue  2         1
2  c   green  3         1
3  b  yellow  4         2
4  b     red  5         3
```